# Program crashes in debugger before anything happens

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I'm building an application for Windows XP using the MinGW tool chain and it sometimes crashes unexpectedly. So, I'm trying to use a debugger (Gdb) but the program exits with code 03 before anything happens. In fact, all I see from GDB is:

> [New thread 3184.0x7b8]
> [New thread
>   3184.0xef8]
>
> Program exited with code 03.

My suspicion is that there is some failed dynamic linking of a dependency (which are Qt, VTK, and ITK, all built with MinGW). However, this does not happen when I just run the program normally. Or if it happens, it appears to be intermittent and well after the program is launched and running. *NOTE: I'm also using Cmake for cross compiling.*

What should I do? What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback via `signal(SIGABRT, <callback>)` to catch the call to abort before it shuts down the process. If this happens before you hit `main()` you might have to resort to a static global and compiler trickery to catch it.

Comment: Yeah. I had to figure this out when our assert macro got rerouted to the macro defined in <assert.h>. It's awesome.

Comment: Cool stuff, I thank thee for a great idea, @MSN, I need to try that myself :)

Comment: If already in GDB, you could try setting a few breakpoints, as well: `catch throw`, and `b raise`, then run your program with whatever args. This should break when either an exception is raised or a signal is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Code 3 is usually returned on a segfault.
Try switching to Linux and debugging the program with electric fence. It might give you some extra insight.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the crashes don't happen anywhere but in Windows.